# Disable "click on header" sorting in GridX

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo.gridx, gridx

Is there a way to disable click-on-header-sort in dojo's GridX ? I would like to still be able to sort it programmaticaly but user need to have that option blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting will happen when you used a module related to that like "`gridx/modules/SingleSort` " or "`gridx/modules/NestedSort`"

You can try un-registering if you have used such modules.

If you want to disable sorting on a specific column of the grid then you can use

```
grid.column(column_Number).setSortable(false);
```

By default "Sort" is set to true